# Wpf Datagrid Delete Row issue

Tags: wpf, datagrid, delete-row

I am new to WPF. I want to delete row from datagrid runtime.When I try to delete row like this

Datagrid.Items.Remove(eRow);

It gives me an error " The error is: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."

I read online that you could use ObservationCollection and InotifyPropertyChangedEvent but I dont know how to implement it.

I have remove button like this

[image]

This is datagrid

```
    <ctrls:RhinoDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Model.CurrentDataTable}"   
                             Style="{StaticResource RhinoDataGridBaseStyle}" IsReadOnly="{Binding Model.IsLinkFile}"
                             SelectedValue="{Binding Model.CurrentDataRow}" SelectedValuePath="Row"
                              >

            </ctrls:RhinoDataGrid>
```

Pls help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Your DataGrid's ItemsSource has a binding on Model.CurrentDataTable. If you want to delete a row, you will have to delete the item in that collection. But the DataGrid won't notice that modification, if the collection does not implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx).

.NET has a builtin [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), which implements INotifyCollectionChanged. If you use this collection type for CurrentDataTable, the DataGrid will update itself, when the collection is modified.

Comment: ObservableCollection<DataTable> dtCollection= this.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<DataTable>;

            dtCollection.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(dtCollection_CollectionChanged); Like this right?

Comment: Well, no. Your underlying data list (Model.DataTable in your original post) should be an ObservableCollection<YourCustomDataClass>, so you can use it as a binding source in the XAML code. The DataGrid will then attach to the CollectionChanged event of your list automatically. Please read the Remarks and the Examples on MSDN. The [Data Binding Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) should help you, too.

Answer (score 1):

WPF Data binding means that you very rarely manipulate the user interface directly. What you're trying to do is directly remove the row from the grid control on the UI, which is how you might have approached things in Winforms.

With WPF data binding the user interface reacts to the underlying data. So in your case the grid is bound onto (or "watching") the contents of the ItemsSource specified by the binding : `Binding Model.CurrentDataTable`

To delete a row, you need to remove it from the underlying data and the UI will automatically reflect the change.

This is what [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) and [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) are all about - you **really** need to read up on them if you're doing WPF development!

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, I want to achieve that only. But my Remove button is ICommand. How can I achieve that.

                    _removeSelectedRowCommand = new DelegateCommand(RemoveSelectedRow, true);
        private void RemoveSelectedRow()
        {
            DataView view = this.ItemsSource as DataView;
            view.Table.Rows[this.SelectedRowIndex].Delete();
            this.Items.Refresh();    
        }